# How to import partial contents of a file into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, load-data-infile

What is the correct syntax to import a part of a file into a MySQL database? For instance, I want to only load lines 50 to line 1000.

Currently my SQL statement imports an entire file into the database.

`LOAD DATA INFILE 'myFile.txt' INTO TABLE myTable (col1, col2) FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`

I want to be more selective. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` only alows you to skip lines at the beginning of the file (by saying e.g. `IGNORE 49 LINES`), but it will import all lines until the end of the file. See [`LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

`head -c 1000 myFile.txt | tail -n 950` would give the 50-1000 lines. I'd recommend separating the pre-processing stage from dataload